# Same PHP script is showing different output in browser than when it's run from command line

Tags: php, multithreading, mongodb

I've a PHP app in the root directory of which there are 2 files named "**database.php**" & "**Thread.php**" (Thread.php has been downloaded from [here](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/)). database.php does some trivial tasks after connecting to a remote MondoDb database. Here's the code for database.php :

```
<?php
include('Thread.php');

$dbUser = 'MyUserName';
$dbPass = 'MyPassword';
$dbHost = 'dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com';
$dbPort = 'xxxxx';
$dbName = 'MyDatabaseName';
$collectionName = 'TestCollection';

function connectToDatabase($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbHost, $dbPort, $dbName) {
    try {
        reconnect:
        echo "connecting to mongodb://{$dbUser}:{$dbPass}@{$dbHost}:{$dbPort}/{$dbName} ...<br/>";
        $database = new MongoClient("mongodb://{$dbUser}:{$dbPass}@{$dbHost}:{$dbPort}/{$dbName}");
        echo "connected ...<br/>";
    }
    catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        goto reconnect;
    }
    return $database->$dbName;
}

$database = connectToDatabase($dbUser, $dbPass, $dbHost, $dbPort, $dbName);

$collection = $database->$collectionName;

function modifyRecent($id, $error, $time) {
     global $database;
     echo "In function modifyRecent ...<br/>";
     //do something
     return;
}

function modifyAll($id, $error, $time) {
     global $database;
     echo "In function modifyAll ...<br/>";
     //do some other things
     return;
}

function updateDatabase($id, $error, $time) {
    echo "In function updateDatabase ...<br/>";
    if( ! Thread::available() ) {
        echo "Thread is not supported ...<br/>";
        return false;
    }

    $thread1 = new Thread('modifyAll');
    $thread2 = new Thread('modifyRecent');

    $thread1->start($id, $error, $time);
    $thread2->start($id, $error, $time);

    while($thread1->isAlive() || $thread2->isAlive()) {}

    return true;
}

updateDatabase((float)"1", (float)"12.6", (float)"23.7");

?>
```

Now when I run this script from shell ( `php database.php` ) ... It's showing an output :

```
user@local_machine:~/AppDir$ php database.php 
connecting to mongodb://MyUserName:MyPassword@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/MyDatabaseName ...<br/>connected ...<br/>In function updateDatabase ...<br/>In function modifyAll ...<br/>In function modifyRecent ...<br/>
user@local_machine:~/AppDir$
```

Which means everything went fine.

but upon running the same script from browser ( **http://app.localhost/database.php** ), the output is :

```
connecting to mongodb://MyUserName:MyPassword@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/MyDatabaseName ...
connecting to mongodb://MyUserName:MyPassword@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/MyDatabaseName ...
connecting to mongodb://MyUserName:MyPassword@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/MyDatabaseName ...
connecting to mongodb://MyUserName:MyPassword@dsxxxxxx.mongolab.com:xxxxx/MyDatabaseName ...
connected ...
In function updateDatabase ...
Thread is not supported ...
```

P.S : I've configured a virtualhost (**http://app.localhost/**) that points to my app's root directory (**~/AppDir**) in order to test it locally.

Can anybody point me out where I'm getting it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use the function `pcntl_fork()` when PHP is used as Apache module. You can only use `pcntl_fork()` in CGI mode or from command-line.

Thread.php makes use of `pcntl_*()` functions.

The reason why `Thread::available()` returns false is because of that. The function is:

```
public static function available() {
    $required_functions = array(
        'pcntl_fork',
    );

    foreach( $required_functions as $function ) {
        if ( !function_exists( $function ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Since you don't have access to modify the server. You can run the PHP file as CGI *possibly* by doing the following, provided your host supports CGI and .htaccess

Create a .htaccess file and put it in the folder where database.php is, and put the following inside it:

```
Action php-script /FULL_PATH_TO_YOU_PHP_BINARY
AddHandler php-script php
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the lines & used the FULL system path. Now both command line version & browser are showing "yes it exists", but for the browser it's still showing "Thread is not supported ..."

Comment: @dibyendu I think we found the problem. This is what someone has said in the PHP documentation : `It is not possible to use the function 'pcntl_fork' when PHP is used as Apache module. You can only use pcntl_fork in CGI mode or from command-line.` So if you are running as Apache module the function `pcntl_fork()` will not work when script is being run in browser, but will run via commandline.

Comment: Setup your local server as CGI and not as Apache module and it should work in both instance then.

Comment: Actually I don't have permission to manipulate the server. The app is hosted on Heroku's cloud. :(

Comment: @dibyendu please see my update. You can try to run as CGI by doing that, if not then I don't know any other way to run as CGI other than changing server config.

Comment: @dibyendu, any luck running as CGI per my instructions in above post?

Comment: when I added the aforesaid lines to my .htaccess file( & placed the file inside the root directory of the app) my browser was showing "Internal server error" & couldn't load the page